# Creating a timelapse with guvcview

Tags: video, time, scheduling, camera, recording

Is there a way to create a timelapse video (or similar) with `guvcview`?

I'm using an external (USB) camera and ordinary footage seems to very quickly fill a hard drive.

Can I get it to record an image/frame or small video once every *n* minutes?

Comment: Hi, did you found the solution for this?

Comment: @Kostanos I haven't used it myself, but try something like this

Answer (score 0):

#### Untested, but one of these ought to work:

```
guvcview -d /dev/video0 -s 640x480 \
-i "timelapse_frame$x.jpg" -c 60 -m 60;

ffmpeg -i "timelapse_frame*" -r 1 'timelapse.mp4'
```

---

```
for x in {0..60); 
do 
    guvcview -d /dev/video0 -s 640x480 \
    -i "timelapse_frame$x.jpg";
    sleep 60; 
done

ffmpeg -i "timelapse_frame*" -r 1 'timelapse.mp4'
```